# Iterate through for loop indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-itertools

I have the following lines of code which I am converting to a function to iterate up to 'n' times

```
import numpy as np

x_set1 = np.array(x_set[0], x_set[0])
x_set2 = np.array(x_set[1], x_set[1])
x_set3 = np.array(x_set[2], x_set[2])

l_set_arr = ((l_set[0], l_set[0]), (l_set[1], l_set[1]))
m_set_arr = (np.linalg.norm(x_set1 - x_set3), np.linalg.norm(x_set2 - x_set3))
```

I have written the following function with multiple `for` loops. Goal is to iterate `x_set` from 0 to n, iterate `l_set_arr` 0 to n-1 and `m_set_arr` uses the output from `x_set_arr`:

```
import numpy as np

def set_arr(x_set_arr, l_set_arr, m_set_arr):
  x_set_arr = []
  l_set_arr = []
  m_set_arr = []

  for i in range(3):
    x_set_arr.append(np.array([set[i], set[i]]))
  x_set_arr1 = np.array(x_set_arr)

  for i in range(2):
    l_set_arr.append(l_set[i], l_set[i])
  print(f"x_set_arr: {x_set_arr1}\nl_set_arr: {l_set_arr}")

  for i in range(3):
    m_set_arr.append(np.linalg.norm(x_set_arr1[i] - x_set_arr1[-1]), np.linalg.norm(x_set_arr1[i+1] - x_set_arr1[-1]) 

  return x_set_arr1, l_set_arr, m_set_arr
```

Doing the above, I have 2 questions:

1. Can someone help me figure out how I can concatenate the `for` loops to do this operation more intelligently? Can I use `itertool.product`?
2. I am getting the following error -
   `IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2` in the `m_set_arr.append` line

Comment: For the second question, `x_set_arr[i+1]` will be out of bounds for `i = 1` as your set only contains 2 elements. Wouldn't that last loop only need to iterate to `n-1`?

Comment: BTW, don't use `set` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: You shouldn't reassign parameter variables.

Comment: Why are `l_set_arr` and `m_set_arr` parameters in the first place? You never use their original contents, you replace them with empty lists.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I incremented the range by 1 and I still see the same error.

Comment: @Barmar I changed the variable name to x_set. Thanks for the suggestion.. And the contents of l_set_arr and m_set_arr will eventually get used outside of the function.. I should probably add return for x_set_arr1, l_set_arr and m_set_arr

Comment: Returning them is necessary. But there's no need for them to be parameters if you ignore the old values.

Comment: Now you also have the same problem for `x_set_arr`.

Comment: `np.array(x_set[0], x_set[0])` doesn't seem valid. The second argument to `np.array()` is the dtype. Why does the original code create 3 arrays, but the function only creates one array?

Comment: Did you mean `np.array((x_set[0], x_set[0]))`?

Comment: @Barmar I do want to create 3 separate arrays like the original code instead of one array. How should I modify the for loop to do that? Apologize for my ignorance

Comment: Then do it just like the original code. Why would it change if it's in a function?

Comment: Yes I exactly meant that. Does this make more sense? `x_set_arr.append(np.array([set[i], set[i]]))` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what you should be doing.

Comment: In the original code, I have 3 separate arrays for `x_set` .. through the function I want to make it iterable so in future if I want 5 separate arrays then I should be able to do that.. which was my intention to create a separate function with a `for` loop in it

Comment: @Barmar Do you have any suggestions on how I can modify the `for` loop for `m_set_arr` to avoid the index error I have mentioned in the original post

Comment: I don't see why changing `range(3)` to `range(2)` wouldn't fix that?